# Youtube onebox overlay title and ► symbol are not displayed correctly in a reply message

Tags: bug, chat, onebox, youtube

I'm talking about the black semi-transparent overlay thing:

[image]

Comment: Is this in chat? Or in a post on sites supporting youtube embedding?

Comment: @ShadowWizard chat.